# Images not displaying when deploying to hosting server

Tags: angular, firebase, deployment

I have an Angular 16 app, using angular/fire 7. The website, along with images displays totally fine on localhost and in a staging area in Firebase, however when I deploy to the hosting server (names.co.uk) the images do not appear. Everything else on the website displays fine, navigation works, etc. but the images are not displayed and I just see the alt tags.

I create a .zip file via PowerShell's Compress-Archive anf upload to the public_html. Should I use 7-Zip instead?

When extracting the dist zip file I receive this error

```
Archive:  /home/xxxxx/appName.zip
warning:  /home/xxxxx/appName.zip appears to use backslashes as path separators
checkdir error:  cannot create assets/images
                 Permission denied
                 unable to process assets/images/logo.webp.
```

In the network tab I get a 403 Forbidden

Also when refreshing any page (apart from the home page) on the live site it gives me the following error page

404 Not Found
The server can not find the requested page:
websiteName.com/about (port 80)

Comment: Server probably does not support .webp?

Comment: There's a mix of webp, png and jpg and none of them are displaying properly. I think part of the issue was using PowerShell's Compress-Archive instead of 7-zip, however it's still not displaying.